# Regex to remove all except XML

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, negate

I need help with a Regex for notepad++ to match all but XML

The regex I'm using:
`(!?\<.*\>)` <-- I want the opposite of this (in first three lines)

The example code:

```
[20173003] This text is what I want to delete [<Person><Name>Foo</Name><Surname>Bar</Surname></Person>], and this text too.
[20173003] This is another text to delete [<Person><Name>Bar</Name><Surname>Foo</Surname></Person>]
[20173003] This text too... [<Person><Name>Lorem</Name><Surname>Ipsum</Surname></Person>], delete me!
[20173003] But things like this make the regex to fail < [<Person><Name>Lorem</Name><Surname>Ipsum</Surname></Person>], or this>
```

Expected result:

```
<Person><Name>Foo</Name><Surname>Bar</Surname></Person>
<Person><Name>Bar</Name><Surname>Foo</Surname></Person>
<Person><Name>Lorem</Name><Surname>Ipsum</Surname></Person>
<Person><Name>Lorem</Name><Surname>Ipsum</Surname></Person>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide the expected result (especially for the last line)?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to do with your input text! but last input line failing is because of using `.` in your pattern, change it to `[^<>]` to not include tag inside other tag names! and add `?` after `*` to stop capturing in first `>` meeting.

Comment: I update with the expected result. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with `(!?\<.*\>)`. That will capture an optional exclamation mark `!` followed by an open fractur bracket, as many characters as possible, and a close fractur bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not perfect, but should work with your input that looks quite simple and well-structured.

**If you need to handle just a single unnested `<Person>` tag**, you may use simple `(<Person>.*?</Person>)|.` regex (that will match and capture into Group 1 any `<Person>` tag and will match any other char) and replace with a conditional replacement pattern `(?{1}$1\n:)` (that will reinsert `Person` tag with a newline after it or will replace the match with an empty string):

[image]

**To make it a bit more generic**, you may capture the opening and corresponding closing XML tags with a recursion-based Boost regex, and the appropriate conditional replacement pattern:

**Find What**:      `(<(\w+)[^>]*>(?:(?!</?\2\b).|(?1))*</\2>)|.`
**Replace With**: `(?{1}$1\n:)`
*`.` matches newline*: `ON`

[image]

**Regex Details**:

- `(<(\w+)[^>]*>(?:(?!</?\2\b).|(?1))*</\2>)` - Capturing group 1 (that will be later recursed with the `(?1)` subrouting call) matching

  - `<(\w+)[^>]*>` - any opening tag with its name captured into Group 2
  - `(?:(?!</?\2\b).|(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of:

    - `(?!</?\2\b).` - any char (`.`) not starting a sequence of `</` + tag name as a whole word with an optional `/` in front
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - the whole  Group 1 subpattern is recursed (repeated)
  - `</\2>` - the corresponding closing tag
- `|` - or
- `.` - any single char.

**Replacement pattern**:

- `(?{1}`  - if Group 1 matches:

  - `$1\n` - replace with its contents + a newline
  - `:` - else replace with an empty string
- `)` -  end of the replacement pattern.

Comment: Excelent solution, great explanation.

Comment: I added a simlified version in case you just need to deal with 1 unnested `<Person>` tag.